# Column name determined by parameter

Tags: t-sql, case

I've tried both approaches. First one has a syntax error. Second one shoves every column in the result instead of just the one that has a match with @LabelID.

```
    SELECT  (SELECT CASE @LabelID
         WHEN 1 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'DIR'
         WHEN 2 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'DD'
         WHEN 3 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'OD_Staff'
         WHEN 4 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'DI_BC'
         WHEN 5 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'DI_PLs'
         WHEN 6 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'DI_PQAs'
         WHEN 7 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'DI_FTEs'
         WHEN 8 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'AIPQBBC'
         WHEN 9 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'AIPQB_PL'
         WHEN 10 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'AIPQB_PQA'
         WHEN 11 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'AIPQB_GS13S'
         WHEN 12 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'AIPQB_FTE'
         WHEN 13 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'IT_Staff'
         WHEN 14 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'IT_Sup'
        )
```

second approach:

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN @LabelID = 1 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) as 'DIR'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 2 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'DD'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 3 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'OD_Staff'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 4 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'DI_BC'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 5 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'DI_PLs'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 6 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'DI_PQAs'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 7 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'DI_FTEs'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 8 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'AIPQBBC'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 9 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'AIPQB_PL'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 10 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'AIPQB_PQA'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 11 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'AIPQB_GS13S'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 12 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'AIPQB_FTE'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 13 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'IT_Staff'
,CASE WHEN @LabelID = 14 THEN count(h.ee_cmn_idfr) END as 'IT_Sup'
```

Comment: Can you show what is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: First one would be a syntax error because your CASE statement syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do it using dynamic SQL:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#INPUT') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #INPUT;

CREATE TABLE #INPUT(RowID       INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
               , ee_cmn_idfr INT);

INSERT INTO       #INPUT(ee_cmn_idfr)
VALUES
      (1),
      (1),
      (1),
      (1),
      (1),
      (1),
      (1),
      (1),
      (1),
      (1),
      (1),
      (1);
```

SQL QUERY:

```
DECLARE @LabelID INT = 1; --<-- set the labelID 

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''; --<-- declare a variable to hold the dynamic sql

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(ee_cmn_idfr) AS '+QUOTENAME(CASE @LabelID
                                                WHEN 1 THEN 'DIR'
                                                WHEN 2 THEN 'DD'
                                                WHEN 3 THEN 'OD_Staff'
                                                WHEN 4 THEN 'DI_BC'
                                                WHEN 5 THEN 'DI_PLs'
                                                WHEN 6 THEN 'DI_PQAs'
                                                WHEN 7 THEN 'DI_FTEs'
                                                WHEN 8 THEN 'AIPQBBC'
                                                WHEN 9 THEN 'AIPQB_PL'
                                                WHEN 10 THEN 'AIPQB_PQA'
                                                WHEN 11 THEN 'AIPQB_GS13S'
                                                WHEN 12 THEN 'AIPQB_FTE'
                                                WHEN 13 THEN 'IT_Staff'
                                                WHEN 14 THEN 'IT_Sup'
                                             END)+' FROM #INPUT'; --<-- you'll have to change the name of the table accordingly 

PRINT(@SQL); --<-- print out the query not needed but nice to have for debuging 

EXEC (@SQL); --<-- execute the dynamic sql
```

the `PRINT(@SQL)` will print the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(ee_cmn_idfr) AS [DIR] FROM #INPUT
```

RESULTS:

[image]

the above code will select the column name as follows:

- WHEN 1  THEN 'DIR'
- WHEN 2  THEN 'DD'
- WHEN 3  THEN 'OD_Staff'
- WHEN 4  THEN 'DI_BC'
- WHEN 5  THEN 'DI_PLs'
- WHEN 6  THEN 'DI_PQAs'
- WHEN 7  THEN 'DI_FTEs'
- WHEN 8  THEN 'AIPQBBC'
- WHEN 9  THEN 'AIPQB_PL'
- WHEN 10 THEN 'AIPQB_PQA'
- WHEN 11 THEN 'AIPQB_GS13S'
- WHEN 12 THEN 'AIPQB_FTE'
- WHEN 13 THEN 'IT_Staff'
- WHEN 14 THEN  'IT_Sup'